# tomcat send same request to all instance of web server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

We have servlet app to do a configuration change (to log4j) to a web server. We have multiple instance of Tomcat web server running on the same machine (As multiple process). This is for load balancing. When we send this configuration change as request from servlet application, we want to apply that change to all the instances. But it is affecting only one instance. We need to retry multiple times, but still it fails to connect to one or two instance (the way load balancing works). Is there any way to send the request automatically to all instance of tomcat.

Comment: When you are "sending" the configuration change how are you doing this? Is it being done as a call or a modification of a file? If it's being done through code then giving that as an example would be useful.

Comment: It is code. It is a log4j logging level change. We just use code like below to set it                                                                                                                            Logger.getLogger("XXXXX").setLevel(Level.INFO);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
Logger.getLogger("XXXXX").setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

You could consider calling

```
Logger.getRootLogger();
```

That will return the root node of the Logger hierarchy which you can then use to call

```
getLoggerRepository();
```

You can then walk through this hierarchy, setting the level at each of the child nodes (note: the documentation states that using `setLevel` on the Root logger may have "catastrophic" effects so don't try that as a shortcut)!

This should allow you to iterate the instances in the way that you expect.

Comment: I dont understand how this will allow me to iterate to all instance. There are several ways to set logging level. That is not the problem here.Could you please explain how to do "This should allow you to iterate the instances in the way that you expect."

Comment: Each instance of Apache has its own Logger, and they sit in a hierarchy. So, it you just use `setLevel()` on the results of the `Logger.getLogger()` call then you will only change the log level for that one instance. This is the behaviour that you're seeing.

Comment: So, instead of that, use the `Logger.getRootLogger()` method to get the base of the tree. At that base level you **may** be able to use `setLevel()` to set the value for all instances (although this isn't recommended). What you'll also find at that level are methods that will let you iterate the hierarchy of Loggers and so individually set the Log Level for each of those instances independently.

Comment: There are some good examples of modifying the log4j log level using `getRootLogger()` [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.apache.log4j.LogManager&method=getRootLogger)

Comment: Thanks for the information, But we can not change root logger level alone. We have many different logger to log different types of messages to different files. if we change root logger level alone, then it will log everything in one file. Also i dont know whether it will affect all the instance as these are separate process (but it doesnt matter as we dont want to change root logger).

Comment: That's not what I suggested. If you call `GetRootLogger` that gives you access to the root of the tree of all of your logger instances. The RootLogger class then has Collections and methods that will allow you to "walk that tree" and look at the contents. This should allow you to decide which loggers you need to modify and which you need to leave alone. As Apache implements the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html) library, it should give you access to all the Apache loggers on that machine. There's no magic wand though, you have to walk the tree.

Comment: If you have different instances on different machines though, you'll likely need to expose some sort of service to process the change because there would need to be an explicit call from one process to the next.